# How to write a file in WPF for Windows Screen Saver

Tags: c#, wpf, file-writing, screensaver

I developed a custom screen saver in WPF (with the extension .scr) but I got an issue :
When screen saver is run by Windows, the application stop imediately. 
After some tests, I found that it comes from the fact that **I'm creating/writing files**.

I tried :

- to add a manifest to run as administrator
- name my file with 8 characters + 3 for extension
- write my file in different location ("C:\", "C:\Windows", "C:\Program Files (x86)",...)

But nothing works...

Any idea ?

**Note :** I need to write lot of lines in my file

Comment: The screensaver cannot write to folders it doesn't have write permissions for. Keep in mind that the screensaver runs under the account of the current desktop user. Choose a directory that is not a restricted directory (for example, you might want your screensaver write to a directory somehwere in the user profile...) Also, make sure to guard all code in your program related to file reading/writing with proper and meaningful exception handling, so you (or your users) actually have a chance to get at least some information about the "why?" when something is going wrong...

Comment: It is extremely suspicious behavior.  Temporarily disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: @elgonzo If I understand, the screensaver can write a file but only in user profile folders ? 
I will try this. Exception handling is a good idea, I always forget it. But I will not have logs if I can't write in a file...

Comment: @HansPassant I will try this too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad... I found where were my problemss.

First, screen saver does not have permission to write in Windows folder.

Then, I was trying to write in a special folder using `Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments` but this property return the name of the folder. So I need to use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` instead.

Finally, I was trying to write a file in a folder that didn't exists. I thought that the folder would be created automatically but I was wrong...

As suggested by @elgonzo, I have added exception handler and displayed the error messages in a message box using `MessageBox.Show(log)`.